# Excel, substring, after text, to character

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I get the sub-string in the following string after "ID: " to the comma? I tried the below code and this worked. I am posting the code so others can view if they need it. Also, posting to see if there are other solutions. I also tried the flash fill with pattern recognition but that did not work for ID's like this:  RD14.01  or RD14.01a.

```
Plans delivered to identify (ID: RD14, Data Store: Physical Boxes)
```

Attempt Code

```
=LEFT(MID(C2,FIND("ID: ",C2)+LEN("ID: "),LEN(C2)),FIND(",",MID(C2,FIND("ID: ",C2)+LEN("ID: "),LEN(C2)))-1)
```

Comment: What version of Excel did you use?

Comment: I am using Version 2008. Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will work:

```
=MID(A1,(FIND("ID:",A1)+4),((FIND(",",A1))-(FIND("ID:",A1)+4)))
```

This is much smaller and neater than that command. Only problem being this command can't take a comma anywhere else in the cell, otherwise this command will break

###### What exactly is happening:

- Finds "ID: " and adds 4 to its index to skip these four characters. this is the start index
- Finds "," and it is the 'end index'
- Length is End-Start
- Gives the substring of A1 from 'start' index of 'end-start' length